# NODE: Configuring babel for the pkg CLI/dev tool

Tags: node.js, json, npm, node-modules, vercel

I am currently running a system level script to run inside a linux envoirnment. The JS is written in ES6. I am trying to package it as a binary for deployment using an NPM library called pkg(https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg), but keep getting errors about certain things like assertion for importing .json and other type:module specific issues.

From what it seems, the Babel that pkg is using is not parsing the ES6 to ES5 properly. How can I configure it to use plugins like ("@babel/plugin-syntax-import-assertions": "^7.22.5") to fix the issue? Using the Babel CLI with a configured .bablerc file seemed to work with no errors.

Here is a snippet from the terminal:
➜  api_server git:(main) ✗ npx pkg index.js -o test

> pkg@5.8.1
> Targets not specified. Assuming:
> node18-linux-x64
> Warning Babel parse has failed: This experimental syntax requires enabling the parser plugin: "importAssertions". (3:47)
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node18-x64 for file /snapshot/api_server/index.js

Comment: The bit you're showing is telling you that you _need_ to tell pkg what platform you're targeting, and you haven't done that yet. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg#targets on the page you link to.

Comment: But I was, and did just resolve part of the issue. npx pkg <js file> -o <new bin file> -t "node18-linux-x64". Now my issue is one of the libraries trying to compile doesn't seemingly know how to handle the architecture, see the update above^

Comment: Then your post was [missing important details](/help/how-to-ask). Show the command(s) you run and the error that generates as a copy-paste (in code fences, to preserve tabs, newlines, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by parsing the ES6 manually to ES5 with the npx babel tool and a plugin configured with a .babelrc file:

```
  {
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          "targets": "node 18"
        }
      ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-assertions"
    ]
  }
```

Then I would run:
npx pkg *babel_parsed_ES6->ES5_js_file* -o *new_bin_file_name* -t "node18-linux-x64" .